# Write file to GCS using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

Trying to write to Google Cloud Storage using a local PySpark session, getting this error:

```
FileSystem: Failed to initialize fileystem gs://vta-delta-lake/test_table: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
```

Full stack trace:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.save.
: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:874)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1942)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:715)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:699)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromPrivateKeyServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:276)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredential(CredentialFactory.java:401)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getCredential(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1341)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.createGcsFs(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1497)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1479)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've configured the Google Cloud Storage Hadoop connector, and I can read from a gcs bucket without any issue, in the same notebook. If I impersonate the service account, I can upload to the bucket without any issue. I just can't write to the bucket using Spark. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Is it DataProc?
You are able to read the data, using spark ? Is it private bucket which you are trying to read/write ? Is write permission there to save content to bucket ?

Comment: Local PySpark, no DataProc. I’ve been able to write to the bucket using the service account via impersonation. Reads work when run via Spark, only writes aren’t working.

Answer (score 1):

Found it - I had been messing with the spark configuration. Originally I had set this property:

spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.keyfile

To point to my service account JSON file. This hadn't worked when trying to read from a bucket, so I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the json file path. This got read working. It seems, though, that when writing the code looks for the config setting above first, and errors out because it's expecting a P12 file. I needed to use this property instead:

spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile

Having set that and restarted PySpark, I can now write to GCS buckets.